# How to get second-order connections using ipython with the following restrictions?

Tags: python, ipython, combinations, python-itertools

I have a connection from region1 to region6 (1->6)
But I want to get second order connections.  In other words: connections from region1 to region2 then region2 to region6. (i.e. 1->2, 2->6)

I want to apply the following restriction: I don't want connections of the same region, such as region1 to region1  (i.e. **1->1**, 1->6) to be listed as a second-order connection.

Note: Region1 to region6 is the same as region6 to region1. In addition I want connections to be listed in descending order. Therefore, if there is a second order connection that goes from region1 to region0 and then from region0 to region6 (1->0, 0->6). I want it to instead be **corrected** to become region0 to region1 and then region0 to region6 (0->1, 0->6).

Also, once all second order connections are performed I want it to be multiplied to get connection of region0 to region1 and then region0 to region6 (ie. 0->1, 0->6).

Once that's done, I want to compare it to the first order connection at the beginning of this question (1->6).  And then I want the program to take the higher value.  and save it.

This is what I have so far:

```
from itertools import combinations

a=print(list(combinations(range(7),2)))

print(list(product(a, repeat=2))
```

Output I get: [(0,1), (0,1)], [(0,1), (0,2)], [(0,1), (0,3)], etc.

This is not what I want

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with itertools. The combinations module appears to be in sorted order, no repeated elements.

```
from itertools import combinations

print(list(combinations(range(7),2)))
```

Itertools are part of included packages in Python, and are excellent in iteratable areas. Read https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html

Beyond combinations is product, which is cartesian product, and permutations,that gives all possible orderings, no repeated elements.

Comment: Thank you for the help. But I don't want to multiply all combinations.  I want to multiply all second order connections.  Meaning if I'm looking at region connecting region2 to region4 (a third region in between)... So, for example, the second order connection I want for (region2->4) is: (2->3,3->4) or (2->1, 1->4).  I hope that makes sense @Prayson W. Daniel